# How to limit Video RAM usage on linux?

Tags: memory, video, ulimit

some processes on my computer are using way too much video card memory for the tasks they're doing. I'd like to impose a limit on these tasks to have the OS limit the on-card RAM usage of these tasks. normally, I could use `ulimit` if the target were the file system, CPU, or system memory. This utility however does not seem to have any capabilities regarding the video card's memory within a PC.

So then this is my question: given that I know the path of an executable that I'd like to impose an upper limit on the consumption of video card memory for, how does one impose such a limit? The card in this case is NVidia based.

Comment: If you reduce the video display resolution does the video ram consumption of these processes also get smaller?

Comment: @SottoVoce in this case, reducing from 4k to 2k does  have a noticeable effect on the memory, though it is minor.

Comment: AFAIK that's currently not possible. No API for that, nothing on the side of NVIDIA.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I'd agree with you. I think you should post your comment as answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK that's currently not possible. No API for that, nothing on the side of NVIDIA.

That looks almost weird and irrational but then there's a likely rationale: GPUs, despite being masively parallel, are often/normally used to a run a single computational task. The only exception I can think of is your Display Manager and your system UI which are running in parallel at all times but then their memory/compute use should be negligible (unless your GPU is over 15 years old but then you shouldn't be running a modern OS and tasks on such an outdated device).